# Windows 10 Firewall Commands - Sharing Local Web Sites on LAN

Tags: windows, networking, firewall

I used to use this series of commands pre Windows 10 in order to enable sharing my development sites on my local network:

- Open up C:\Users\\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
- Find your site definition and add in a new binding ” />
- Open Command Prompt (as admin) netsh http add urlacl url=http://:54275/ user=everyone
- Then execute netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”IISExpressWeb” dir=in protocol=tcp localport=54275 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow
- Then point your remote machines to http://:54275

However I've just gone through these same steps on my local Windows 10 box and the Firewall is still blocking requests.

Turning Windows Firewall off completely and the sites start serving the requests.

Anyone have an info on what changed and a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've spent the last few hours dealing with this same issue.  I'm not sure what your binding entry in the applicationhost.config file looks like, but I had a generic entry. Similar to this:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:12345:*" />
```

It worked in Windows 8.1 but not when I upgraded to Windows 10.  After changing the entry to a specific IP address things starting flowing again.  Like this:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:12345:192.168.1.100" />
```

Comment: Interesting.  I actually already have a binding configured as per your second example and it's still not working.  The problem isn't the binding it's the Windows Firewall commands to open the ports that seems off.

Comment: Hmm... Have you run a:  "netsh http show urlacl" in cmd to verify the URL reservation?  It should have a the IP address in there like "http://192.168.1.100:12345/".  I noticed in your post you didn't have that.  Also, is this an upgrade to Windows 10 that was working prior to the upgrade or is a first time setup?

Comment: I have those entries now as i manually configured it in Windows Firewall, so checking that doesn't help.  I'm going to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new rule on Windows Firewall for the Port specifically. Choose "Add new rule" and then Choose "Port" and specify the port number that you want to use. I had a similar issue.

Comment: Could you expand on this with some screenshot? Please see [answer].